# CaptchaMVC image route not working with my current routes in MVC3 - how to resolve?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, routes

After installing [CaptchaMVC](https://nuget.org/packages/CaptchaMvc.Mvc3/1.0.1) I navigated to the page where I want to test the functionality - ~/about.

For the image `localhost:51860/DefaultCaptcha/Generate?t=6d9ab0cefbb8496582b1db592eff66f`, I see a broken link.

I added `routes.IgnoreRoute("DefaultCaptcha/{*pathInfo}");` and also tried `routes.IgnoreRoute("DefaultCaptcha/Generate");` to the top of my routes, but the image still does not appear, and navigating to the image url returns with a 404 not found error.

When I remove all my routes from Global.asax, this works fine.

The issue I think is that this pattern matches this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "WholeCountryCategoryResults1", url: "{categoryName}/{searchTerm}/", defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchWholeCountryCategory" });
```

The rest of the routes shouldn't matter, as the rules are executed in order, so what's the issue here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those that may experience the same issue, simply setup a route to the captcha provider's controller and action:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "DefaultCaptchaRoute", url: "DefaultCaptcha/Generate", defaults: new { controller = "DefaultCaptcha", action = "Generate" });
```

Comment: This can only work if you have the source code. Right? The CaptchaMVC code is no longer accessible on CodePlex. this is not working for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: The image only works when I login into the login page first. Once the user is authenticated, it works. The page can be accessed right now without being an authenticated user but the image does not load unless you are an authenticated user/Logged in user

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me. Add this to the web.config

```
 <location path="DefaultCaptcha/Generate">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```